# Does the spelling of suffixes change in some cases like prefixes?

Tags: orthography, suffixes, prefixes, affixes, example

I know that prefixes never change the spelling of the stem. However, their spelling changes in some cases. For example:

- well+come = welcome (not wellcome)
- all+ways =  always (not allways)
- in+regular = irregular (not inregular)

According to some websites I've reviewed, *suffixes sometimes change the spelling of the stem*. Does it mean *their own spelling never changes* or sometimes it is possible?

Is it a valid deduction to say: Suffixes sometimes change the spelling of the stem, but their own spelling never changes. However, prefixes never change the spelling of the stem, but their own spelling sometimes changes.

Comment: The examples you have aren't great. Look for example at *welcome*. In Old English, that was "wilcume" with the first part being the verb "willen" (modern English "will"), which was often spelled with a single L. Additionally, *welcome* itself was often spelled with two Ls.

Comment: Unlike Turkish, which has a recently-designed scientific orthography, English spelling is full of inconsistencies and contradictions, to the point where the spelling of a word and its pronunciation must be learned separately, like its meaning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on how you define suffixes. You could say that notoriety and spontaneity end in the same suffix spelled two different ways (-ety and -ity).

The very common suffix *-(e)s* also changes based on its base: *kid* goes to *kid**s*** but *kiss* goes to *kiss**es***.